# undefined method `users_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<%= form_for @user1 do |f| %>

    Username: <%= f.text_field :username %>      <br />
    Password: <%= f.password_field :password %>  <br />.
    Email:    <%= f.email_field :email %> <br />

    <%= submit_tag "Add" %>

<% end %>
```

I am new on ruby and I am trying create simple programs, but I have this error and I can't find out why. I have this error

```
undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000020576f0>:0x0000000335d5d8>
```

what is the solution here?

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def add
    @user1 = User.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render :json => @user1}
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 23):

Did you define the [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) in `config/routes.rb`?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  # ...
end
```

Comment: By putting that line inside `Rails.application.routes.draw`. Please read the [routing guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: I added resources :users, but now I have an error on username

Comment: "What is @user1 - how is it created? – DGM 11 mins ago"

Answer (score 0):

In your class `UserController`, use:

```
route: get /signup, to: 'user#new'
.
.
resources :users
```

where "`:users`" is plural, because you will register multiple *users*.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when in my `config/routes.rb`, I mistakenly had `user` (singular):

```
resources :user
```

It needs to be `users` (plural):

```
resources :users
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the `rake routes` command, you will find that there is no entry for `users_path` in the very first column.  What that means is that you have no route defined for action that will be called when the form is submitted.

If you want to use resources, then just add:

```
resources: users
```

and if you want to use a different `URL(route name)` for the `users#new` action, then add

```
resources: users, except: [:new]
```

below the route for `users#new` in the routes.rb file.

And, if you don't want to go the resources way then add a new route:

```
post 'users', to: 'users#create'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/routes.rb` file add:

```
resources :users, except: [:new]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This happens when we have a form and Rails doesn't know where to submit the form when we press the submit button.
For this, we need to go to routes and make sure we have `resources:users`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

#all the other resources and routes

resources :users

end
```

In one of the other answers, I saw

```
resources :users, except[:new]
```

Use this only if we have already introduced the new action in the routes:

```
resources :posts

get 'signup', to: 'users#new 

resources :users, except[:new]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read
 "[answer]" and its linked pages, and "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)". Grammar is important on SO as SO is not a discussion board, it's more of a text book of programming Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your UserController, you should already have a route in the config/routes.rb file similar to this:

```
get 'users', to: 'user/#add'
```

In this case, Rails is going to look for a post users-route. So you need to define it too in the routes.rb file:

```
post 'users', to: 'user/#create'
```

To combine these two routes, you can simply add the following to your routes file:

```
resources: users
```

Which will automatically generate all the users related routes. You can have a look by typing in the terminal:

```
rails routes
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `form_with` helper instead.

The `form_with` helper is looking for a URL to handle the POST request. It defaults to `(lower-case model name) + _new_path`, but you can override it by specifying `url`:

```
<%= form_with(model: user, url: login_path) do |form| %>
```

See output from `rails routes` to select the appropriate path.